# Getting 3 random records from a table

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've read multiple answers to a similar query, but none seem to hit the spot.

Imagine I have a table that contains 10 rows, how do I retrieve 3 random rows from this table using Entity Framework?  Not just 1 random row, but 3 random rows - each being different from the other?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var threeRandomFoos = foos.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
```

Comment: Now that is simplicity awesome!  Cheers Darin!

Answer (score 8):

Instead, there is a simpler way,

```
var threeRandomFoos = foos.OrderBy( x=> SqlFunctions.Rand()).Take(3);
```

Guid.NewGuid will be little slower in performance, why not use Random specified by SqlFunctions itself?

Comment: It seems that `Rand` is evaluated only once and therefore is not useful : I have a sql query that looks like `SELECT TOP (3) 
--some columns...
FROM ( SELECT 
 RAND() AS [C1], 
 -- some columns...
 FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC`. I am using Sql-Server 2008 R2.